# Skrollr not working on IE

Tags: skrollr

I'm trying to get skrollr.js to work on IE. I copied over the example code from the skrollr site: view-source:http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/
included all the other js files including the ie file. It works fine on all the browsers accept the wonderful IE. Can't work out what the problem is.

Comment: please add some code and the list of .js files you are using.

Comment: skrollr.ie.js
skrollr.js

view-source:http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

The code is at the source from the github site as linked above.

Comment: theirs works on IE, so there is something you are not doing right. We need to see what you are doing before we can help.

Comment: I'm really just trying to copy everything over from the example I listed and include the same js files as I listed above. It works completely fine on anything but IE. I really can't see what I've missed out. It's the end of the work day for me now. I'm going to re do everything again tomorrow from scratch and give a more detailed list of everything.

Comment: Interesting enough the http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.ie.min.js file is 404 (I will fix this), so maybe it's an issue with the file (if you included it and the page doesn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download respond.js and html5shiv.js. you can just google those. add them to your code like this.

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ie8.css">
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
```

Comment: Cool thanks I'll try this tomorrow and let you know how it goes :D